# iOS - What happened when I'm doing addSubview & removeFromSuperView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I recently found the method `addSubview` & `removeFromSuperView` are very time-consuming.

When I used these methods in `cellWillAppear` & `prepareForReuse`, it's actually causing some scrolling performance issue. I checked the time profiler and it indicated that these two methods(`addSubview` & `removeFromSuperView`) were taking a bunch of time.

However, I don't understand why these methods are slow. It seems like they are just setting up the parent pointer and add something into the subViews array.

All the views are pre-allocated btw.

Any helps are more than appreciate!

Comment: Update your question with relevant code (as text, properly formatted).

Comment: Well, I don't known what exactly happens when a view is added or removed, but there's not much you can do about it. Maybe the view removed gets dealloced, which is time consuming.  If it's to slow for you, maybe setting a view's `isHidden` property will work.

Comment: Maybe you change the view hierarchy at the wrong method... cellWillAppear is just before cell is shown, and right than you change the view hierarchy and triggers a new layout pass... try to do it sooner and only do last minute customizations in cellWillAppear